# htm files as resources in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, resources, html-email, globalization

My site is globalized. For email notifications I use an .htm files for the email body. Is there a way I can have a .htm file for each language and call that file based on the culture settings of the browser? I do this for all the strings on the page, but I can't find a way to add a .htm file to a resource set. What's the best way to do this? I really need to translate my website email notifications but am struggling with this.

Any help or a point in the right direction appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since .htm files are static files, they cannot be localized. Here is what I do. Instead of using mail.htm, use mail_en-US.htm, mail_tr-TR.htm, etc.

`string file = String.Format("mail_{0}.htm" , Thread.CurrentUICulture);`

Comment: thanks! sounds like a perfect solution, don't know why I didn't think of that! I'll give it a go thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

The email will send and after there what is contained inside is static and you can not change it.

What you can do is to check the user language and send the correct html file at the first time.

So the trick is what you send.

Comment: Aristos... this is what i am trying to do, choose the correct file to use for the body before sending the email.

Comment: @Stuart Ok, there programmatically you select the correct html. You do not wait from the html to do that by him self.